# How do I add pyinstaller to PATH?

Tags: python, path, pyinstaller

I have a pygame project stored in C:\Users\name\GameProject. I followed instructions to create an exe by typing in pyinstaller --onfile -w game.py. However, every time it tells me that pyinstaller is not recognized as an internal or external command. I googled some answers, and apparently python is not in my path. The problem is, I've added everything I could to both the user path and system path. I even reinstalled python, checking add to path. Pyinstaller still is unable to make me an exe file. Can I have some insight on why this might be? I'm on windows 10, using python 3.9.

Comment: Have you installed pyinstaller?

Comment: Yes I have, with pip installer

Comment: What PATH did you add? was it like this `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts`

Comment: No it was more like C:\Users\username\AppData\Local. I also check add python to path when installing. I even found the location of python on my computer and put that directory into path. I googled how to check if python is in path, and I'm pretty confident that I have python in my path. But if pyinstaller is in python, why is it still not working?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding pyinstaller to PATH, you can use `python -m  PyInstaller path/to/your/python/script.py`

Answer (score 1):

To everyone that has the same problem as me, if you are using PyCharm, make sure to install pyinstaller on the project interpreter as well! It worked for me.

If you don't know how:

1. Click file at the top left corner
2. Click settings
3. Find your project on the toolbar on the left
4. Click project interpreter
5. To the right there will be a plus sign
6. Click that and search pyinstaller
7. Install

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I know that this might seem odd but try this:

- try uninstalling python, then reinstalling it "make sure you press
  add to PATH".
- when you do install it again, restart your device and open the
  command prompt.
- type `pip install pyinstaller`.

I encountered the same issue and when I did this it worked perfectly.
it's definitely an environmental variable issue.