# I want to make .exe file, but facing an error

Tags: python, pyinstaller

[image]

Here I'm using python 3.9.0

```
pyinstaller : The term 'pyinstaller' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Comment: ```pip install pyinstaller``` did you install ```pyinstaller```?

Comment: If you have installed `pyinstaller`, maybe the pyinstaller path not in system's PATH.

Comment: Yes, I installed it.

Comment: Find the "pyinstaller" executable in the Python installation and use its full path on command line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyinstaller is not recognized as internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45951964/pyinstaller-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: C:\Users\Shashi Kumar>AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts>pyinstaller copy.py

   'AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You are in the wrong Program. You can't execute pyinstaller from the PowerShell. You have to open a command shell terminal. See my answer below.

Comment: You have not installed `pyinstaller` as Administrator, but for a single user. Did you really mean to do that?

Answer (score 1):

So pyinstaller isn't on your path

According to WikiPedia A path is a string of characters used to uniquely identify a location in a directory structure. It is composed by following the directory tree hierarchy in which components, separated by a delimiting character, represent each directory.

Checkout this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65399842/how-do-i-add-pyinstaller-to-path) from Stackoverflow it will help you

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are not in the shell but in Microsoft PowerShell. That's something completely different. Even if it looks a little like a command shell.

Exit the PowerShell and open the command shell by pressing "Windows Logo"+R, enter `cmd` and hit OK. Then, you can execute pyinstaller.

Alternatively (and sometimes much easier), you can create a Batch file to execute the pyinstaller command line with all necessary options. Just create an empty text file, write the command in it, write `pause` on the last line and store it with the extension `.BAT`. You can then double-click it to execute the command. (`pause` is necessary to keep the terminal open until you have read all messages, warnings and errors)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by this process.
Run this command in the respective path where you got an error.

```
pip uninstall pyinstaller
```

go to main python folder `C:\Users\USER NAME\AppData\Roaming\Python`
and open powershell window in the python path and Now run this command.

```
pip install pyinstaller
```